# HM-10 BLE not working as iBeacon

Tags: android, bluetooth, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, hm-10

I am trying to make HM-10 module (CC2541 chip) into iBeacon. My firmware version is v540. I set the module up using these commands:

AT+RENEW Restores factory defaults

AT+RESET Reboot HM-10

AT Wait for OK

AT+MARJ0x1234 Set iBeacon Major number to 0x1234 (hexadecimal)

AT+MINO0xFA01 Set iBeacon Minor number to 0xFA01 (hexadecimal)

AT+ADVI5 Set advertising interval to 5 (546.25 milliseconds)

AT+NAMEYOURNAME Set HM-10 module name to YOURNAME. Make this unique.

AT+IBEA1 Enable iBeacon mode

AT+RESET Reboot

When I open any Beacon Scanner app then it does not show me the right distance, it always shows me 0.1 meter (although I am 3 meter away). Any suggestion why this is not working for me? I followed the instructions from here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-your-CC2541-based-HM-10-Bluetooth-Smart-Modul/

Comment: The RSSI value in the BLE Scanner app is always between -48 to -46. Even if I am 10 meters away.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the distance estimates working properly, you need to set the measured power byte within the beacon packet to a specific value that represents the expected RSSI of the beacon transmitter at 1 meter.

To do this, use a beacon app like my Locate Beacon app here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en and perform a calibration measurement at 1 meter away.

Then you need to take this RSSI value (e.g. -59 dBm) and convert it to a two's complement hex value (for -59 it would be 0xC5).  Then put this value into the appropriate position in your packet to be transmitted inside the HM-10.

Comment: I am quite new to BLEs. My hex value is 0xE9. Which packet do I need to change and how? Do you mean that I have to change the UUID with AT commands? Thank you for your help David.

Comment: There hopefully is another AT command to set the measured power value.  I am no expert on the HM-10, so you'll need to check the docs for it to see if that is possible and what command to use.

Comment: Looking at the data sheet, you use AT+MEAS0xE9 to set your measured power.

Comment: AT+MEAS0xE9 or AT+MEAS? commands do not give any answer. This command is added since V519 version. Since I have V540 version it should work but it does not. Have you got a clue why MEAS command is not working for me?